# SAS transpose wide to long with duplicates

Tags: sas, transpose

I am going to transpose the following table:

X     Y1     Y2     Y3

a      1       2        3

a      2       3        4

b      7       8        9

To

X     Y

a      1

a      2

a      3

a      2

a      3

a      4

b      7

b      8

b      9

I tried this code

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=table1 OUT=table2;
BY X;
RUN;
```

However, it gave me this output

X     COL1       COL2

a      1                2

a      2                3

a      3                4

b      7

b      8

b      9

Does anyone how to get the table that I need?

Appreciate any thoughts, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

something like below should work

```
data want;
set have;
array name(*) Y1--Y3;
do i = 1 to dim(name);
Y=name[i];
output;
end;
Drop y1 y2 y3 i;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, it adds a row and then transpose based on row. Since the row numbers will be unique

```
data have;
input X $ Y1 Y2 Y3;
datalines;
a 1 2 3
a 2 3 4
b 7 8 9
;
run;

data have;
set have;
row=_n_;
run;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=have OUT=want(rename=(COL1=Y) drop=_NAME_ row);
by row x;
RUN;

proc print data=want; run;
```

Comment: You can/should RENAME and DROP using "data set options" in TRANSPOSE step.

Comment: @data _null_.. thanks for you suggestion. Updated code.